# Restart Button after Dying in a game

Tags: unity-game-engine

Yo, I'm creating a death screen in my game in unity and I'm trying to program a restart button. My idea was to create a variable on start , which will store a number of first level and will iterate on finish of the level, so I created it as a public int in script for starting a game and when I got my death screen and clicked "Restart" button I've got a ERROR saing [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zcL2H.png, as it was not declared.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML6Me.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv9Nq.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXZMd.png

Can someone tell me how to create a public variable on start of the game or show me what I did wrong or give me a better solucion to do a Restart button? I would've been gratefull. Also sorry that I can show screens normally bc I'm new here.

Comment: You should add a screenshot of your code in order to better understand why Unity is throwing the Null Reference. Otherwise, I'm only able to guess that you forgot to initialize or assign your variable at the start of the game.

Comment: No screenshots of code please. Add the text of your program and format it properly.